# Como colocar botão em um Listview?

Tags: android

Eu tenho um modelo que uso nos meus projetos, de lista com imagem, quero que ao invés da imagem do lado fique o botão, apenas botão e título. Vejam meu adapter:

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

  private LayoutInflater mInflater;
  private ArrayList<Categoria> itens;

  public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<Categoria> itens) {
    //Itens que preencheram o listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  /**
   * Retorna a quantidade de itens
   *
   * @return
   */
  public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
  }

  /**
   * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
   *
   * @param position
   * @return
   */
  public Categoria getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
  }

  /**
   * Sem implementação
   *
   * @param position
  * @return
  */
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Pega o item de acordo com a posção.
    Categoria item = itens.get(position);
    //infla o layout para podermos preencher os dados
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    //atravez do layout pego pelo LayoutInflater, pegamos cada id relacionado
    //ao item e definimos as informações.
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getTexto());
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());
  //  ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo)).setText(item.getSubtitulo());

    return view;
  }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5sp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemview"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FF000000" />    
  </LinearLayout>
```

Tentei apenas trocar `((ImageView)` por `((Button)` , porém não deu certo.

Comment: Quando você trocou (ImageView) por (Button) você fez no XML e no JAVA ?

`<ImageView android:id="@+id/imagemview" .../>`
 - 
`((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview))`

Comment: isso, troquei tudo por botao, porem veja que no de imageView tem um metodo setImageResource, queria saber como vai ficar no botao

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um `ImageButton`?

Comment: No botão você pode usar `setText` e o `setOnClickListener` para capturar o evento. Ou usar o `ImageButton` como @sicachester disse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for para substituir a `ImageView` por `Button` você também terá que substituir o método `setImageResource` por um que o [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) possui como o `setText`.

```
//((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());
((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setText("meu botão");
```

e utilizar o `setOnClickListener` para capturar o evento.

Caso você queira utilizar a imagem como botão você pode utilizar o [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) e mater `setImageResource` ou utilizar um equivalente.

Comment: a implementação do clique é feita normalmente na activity?

Comment: Sim, mas não precisa ser na activity, você pode fazer a implementação nesta classe.

Comment: mas eu vou ultilizar variaveis de outra activity

Comment: Então se eu não estou enganado, na sua activity você chama uma `setAdapter` passando a instancia da sua `AdapterListView`, se for isso você pode criar a sua `OnClickListener` na activity e criar um método na `AdapterListView` para você passar como variável antes do `setAdapter`, assim quando ele começar a desenha (`getView` da `AdapterListView`) você já tem a `OnClickListener` da activity disponível.